# Small standalone SQL database similar to access in the old days(ie file database)

Tags: sql, database, deployment, sql-server-ce

I am looking for a easy to use and deploy sql type database i can ship with a desktop application.

This will be a small application user's can download from my website.

In the vb6 days, access was the common database for small desktop apps, what is my option these days?

Looking at SQL CE it seems to have a quite a few limitations such as count(distinct) etc

SQL express needs to be installed and running as a service (could i include the SQL express deployments in my deployment so the user doesn't even know its been installed? I assume size would then be an issue)

SQL 2005/2008 is not an option due to size and licensing restrictions.

I would like to use c#, wpf and entity framework.

What would seem to be the best options based on your knowledge and experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) (also see [corresponding wrappers](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers) for the .NET Framework) might do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

[FirebirdSQL](http://www.firebirdsql.org). More functions, plus UDFs made in C/C++ or even Delphi.